# How to write a method that returns how many number 2 are present in an integer without a do loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

This is what i have:

```
int count = 0;
do {
    if(number % 10 == 2){
        count++;
    }
    number = number /10;

} while (number > 0);

return count;
```

It works fine but is there a way to write it without using the do loop? I have an assignment that doesn't allow it

I'm new at java so let me know if you need me to clarify something let me know

Comment: Are you allowed to substitute a different kind of loop for the `do...while`?

Comment: I can only use for or while loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is a 'do-while' loop which is an exit control loop and I'm glad you are trying to learn how to convert between loops. 
The most useful and efficient loop for this code is going to be the 'while' loop since the 'for' loop is usually used for iterations in which we know the end goal or number of interations on the whole.

```
public int method(int number){

int count = 0;
    while(number > 0) {
        if (number % 10 == 2) {
            count++;
        }
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The above example is for your code to be converted to the 'while' loop. The basic code is the same however the java statement in the 'do' bloc become the part of the 'while' bloc.

It is not recommended to use the 'for' loop here since it is going to complicate the process unneccsarily however for the sake of curiosity this is the code.

```
public int method(int number){
    int count;
for(count = 0; number > 0 ; count++){
    if((number % 10) != 2){
        count--;
    }
    number = number / 10;
}
return count;
}
```

The above code is one way of executing the 'for' loop. Note that in the 'for' loop the count increases without any condition hence, in the loop we have added a `count--` to prevent the unintended increment in the `count` variable.

I have used something called 'shorthand operators' which can make statements like `number = number / 10` smaller like this, `number /= 10`.

Do let me know if you find anything complicated and keep experimenting. It's rare to find the questions like these which are conceptual and technically basic but I am glad this community is vast.
Let me know about any further queries, I had a lot of fun answering this!

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of ways to approach this. The while code looks pretty similar to your do-while:

```
int count = 0;
while(number > 0) {
    if (number % 10 == 2) count++;
    number /= 10;
}
return count;
```

String replace is a cute tactic (though perhaps not efficient):

```
// total length - length without 2s = length of 2s
String numStr = String.valueOf(num);
int count = numStr.length() - numStr.replace("2", "").length()
```

[Elliot's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) version is even sexier:

```
// Replace all "not 2s" and count length
int count = String.valueOf(num).replaceAll("[^2]", "").length();
```

Comment: I think I like `int count = String.valueOf(num).replaceAll("[^2]", "").length();` (note `int.toString()` is not valid).

Comment: Good catch on the toString; I've been blissfully ignorant to this writing Kotlin recently! Nice answer too!

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
while(number > 0) {
    if(number % 10 == 2) {
        count++;
    }

    number /= 10;
}
```

The only difference is that a while loop will only run if its condition is met, while a do-while loop will run at least once.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Sample{
     static int count = 0;
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(Sample.Count(50));
     }

     public static int Count(int number){

        if(number>0){
            if(number%10==2){
                count++;
            }
            number = number/10;
            Count(number);
        }
        return count;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a misuse of static variables if I ever saw one. It took me a while to understand what `Count(number);` was doing there, so you might want to explicitly point out what's going on with your code.

Comment: Also, to any beginner stumbling upon this answer: Never *ever* write code that does this.

Comment: Can you make it tail recursive? Bonus points if you also make it pure.